# Notes : Change 'Password quality' by Notes API

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'd like to change 'Password quality' level for lots of Notes user IDs. However I can' find the way to accomplish it by Notes API. Is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about APIs, but you might be able to get what you want using a Policy with Security Settings in the Domino Directory. This is administrative configuration, and doesn't use an API or any programming.

A Policy with Security Settings can set "required password quality". I've never modified this option, but I think that it would affect the initial password for new users, and existing users only if they change their password.
It probably has no effect on existing users if they don't change their password.

If you wanted to force users to change their password to comply with a higher quality, there's a separate option for "required change interval", but no way (that I can see) to only enforce that for low-quality passwords.

Comment: Thanks for useful information! The solution works for my requirement! Thank!!